# Is it possible to securely connect 20AWG wire to CR2 battery terminals?

Tags: batteries, connector, terminal, wire-terminals

I’m trying to securely connect a positive and negative 20 AWG thickness wire to each terminal of a CR2 battery.

From what I understand, they don’t make terminal connectors for these types of batteries as the negative end is flat and positive end has a nub like most small consumer batteries.

For the time being, I am wrapping electrical tape around each end of the battery to hold the wires in place.

I am aware that this is only a temporary solution and would like something that would be much more secure.

Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Get a battery holder for CR2.  [Keystone makes those](http://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Cylindrical-Cell-Holders-Cost-Effective/Half-AA-Size/id/663), for example.

Comment: Don’t solder to it!!! I almost lost my vision on both eyes due to a quick-and-dirty “fix” on a loose CR battery connection. They don’t have vent holes nor weakened structure to rupture in any semi-safe manner. Just nothing-nothing-nothing-BAM!

Comment: What about superglue as a quick and dirty fix?  I agree, would never solder to battery!

Comment: Hopefully the battery holder will fit in the small tight space that I am working in

Comment: Cold weld is best (ultrasonic)

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper CR2 battery holder.  This will use spring pressure against the contacts for good connection, and you can easily change the battery when necessary.

Definitely do not try to solder wires to the battery.

Examples:

[EBay](https://www.ebay.com/i/261731131639?chn=ps)

[Keyelco](http://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Cylindrical-Cell-Holders-Cost-Effective/Half-AA-Size/id/663)

[Misumi](https://us.misumi-ec.com/vona2/detail/222000222495/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd give conductive epoxy a try.  Probably smaller than the holders and won't come loose like tape.  Just kinda pricey

[https://www.amazon.com/MG-Chemicals-Two-Part-Conductive-Adhesive/dp/B008UH4DB2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008UH4DB2)

Comment: Wow! It is pricey, but basically the next best thing next to soldering and it seems to be fairly easy to apply? I would only use the smallest amount to connect the thin wires to the battery

Comment: looks like you can get a smaller amount too for 12 bucks
https://www.amazon.com/Electrically-Conductive-Adhesive-Temperature-AA-DUCT/dp/B00EPYCIGQ